# Wanted: In-depth guide to virtualizing existing Windows 7 partition with VirtualBox

Tags: 13.10, partitioning, windows-7, virtualbox, virtualization

I would like an in-depth guide to virtualizing an existing Windows 7 partition (with VirtualBox), as all the instructions I have found online are either incomplete, imperfect,vaguely worded, or out of date. I find it surprising that there isn't a good in'depth guide to such a, as I assume, common problem.!This is not to be considered a duplicate, as there is not one satisfying answer to any of the similar posts out there! Help would be much appreciated by newbie. 
Desired Results:
 -one installation of Win7, accessible both via boot menu and VM
 -Preferrably as little as possible problems with drivers & reactivation
Thanks in advance.

Instructions that didn't suit my needs:
http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#rawdisk - doesn't address driver/reactivation problem

http://geekery.amhill.net/2010/01/27/virtualbox-with-existing-windows-partition/ - out-of-date, vague
and others, which I don't have enough reputatioins at the moment to post links to...

Comment: Which platform will the hardware be running? If Ubuntu, which version? http://superuser.com/questions/121820/possible-to-take-a-snapshot-of-a-hard-disc-and-use-it-in-a-virtual-machine/121824#121824 provides links if your hardware is running Windows.  PS: You may wish to review a discussion at SuperUser to optimize the Win7 image:  http://superuser.com/questions/251599/tuning-windows-7-for-use-in-a-vm

Comment: There may be a licence issue, as we would need to run one Windows key on two machines (1 bare metal & 1 virtual). As this is not conform with the Windows licence I believe we can only run a virtual Windows in a VM on an Ubuntu host, or a dual boot Windows, but not both.

Comment: This is just not allowed by the Windows license, you are going to run into problems with activation unless you install a cracked Windows, and if you do you will run into problems with Windows updates (not to mention the law).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, found the best guide here: http://fds-team.de/cms/articles/2013-12/use-a-real-windows-7-partition-in-virtualbox-kvm-vmware-player-u.html (might not work on GPT installations of Windows)